# How to set NStextfield displayed as **** return character when checkbox in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm a newbiwe. I building a mac app, i want to set type input in password textfield displayed as ****. And then user check on Checkbox, text in password textfield displayed normal. I created NStextfield and Checkbox programmitically. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [KSPasswordField](https://github.com/karelia/SecurityInterface)...

From the page:

> - Shows the password in plain text on-demand
> - On the basis that password visibility is likely being toggled for editing, makes the field the first responder
> - Automatically cleans up likely unwanted whitespace when pasting or dragging in passwords

To make it work:

1. Add `KSPasswordField.h` and `KSPasswordField.m` to your project.
2. In Interface Builder, create a regular `NSSecureTextField` and then set
   its custom class to be `KSPasswordField`. 
   (Or, in your case, programatically create a `KSPasswordField` instead of an `NSTextField`)
3. Hook up a checkbox (`NSButton`) to the `toggleTextShown:` action of your `KSPasswordField`. In your case, do this:

   ```
   [myCheckbox setTarget:myPasswordField];
   [myCheckbox setAction:@selector(toggleTextShown:)];
   ```

Comment: Thanks but how can do "In Interface Builder, create a regular NSSecureTextField and then set its custom class to be KSPasswordField. "? Can you show me? Thanks much

Comment: @user2656381 I assume you've already got something like `[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:etc...]` in your code if you are creating the textfield programatically. In that case, all you need to do is `#import "KSPasswordField.h"` in that file, change `NSTextField` to `KSPasswordField` and add the two lines of code shown in my answer's step 3 right after you programatically create the checkbox.